# OpenSSL C Cryptopals Challenge7

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

I have been trying to learn OpenSSL C API. I found the interesting [cryptopals](https://cryptopals.com/) challenges page and wanted to try some easy challenge. I took challenge 7, AES ECB: https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/7

After reading OpenSSL documentation I wanted to do some coding. I copy pasted most of the code below from the OpenSSL wiki page. But somehow I cannot make this work. I tried to google for the error and found that people solved this challenge easily in [Python](https://laconicwolf.com/2018/07/22/cryptopals-challenge-7-implement-aes-in-ecb-mode-with-python/), but found nothing for C.

The input file is encoded in Base64, with newlines. So first what I did was to remove newlines. I did it manually, not programatically, with tr tool.

```
tr -d '\n' < cipertext > ciphertext.no_newlines
```

Next I decoded it, also manually:

```
base64 -d ciphertext.no_newlines > ciphertext.no_newlines_decoded
```

Next I copied mostly everything from this OpenSSL webpage https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption:

The encrypt and decrypt functions are exact copies from the documentation. I modified only the main function. I also copied from somewhere the readFile function (tested that it works OK).

I compile it like this:

```
gcc -I /opt/openssl/include challenge7.c /opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a -lpthread -ldl -o challenge7
```

But I receive this error:

```
140095710082880:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:570:
[1]    24550 abort (core dumped)  ./challenge7
```

I googled this error and found that it may be related to incompatibilities between OpenSSL versions, i.e. the one that was used to encrypt the file, and the one I have on my computer. Can it be really the reason for this? If so then this is the crappiest library ever, that I cannot decrypt file with different version of the library using the same algorithm. I somehow cannot believe that. I heard that OpenSSL is crappy, but somehow I don't believe this is the reason for this error.

Can someone help me spot what I keep doing wrong here? The whole code is below:

```
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <string.h>

char* readFile(char* filename, int* size) 
{
    char* source = NULL;

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END) == 0) {
            long bufsize = ftell(fp);
            if (bufsize == -1) {
                fputs("ftell error", stderr);
            } else {
                source = malloc(sizeof(char) * (bufsize + 1));
                if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET) != 0) { 
                    fputs("fseek error", stderr);
                }

                size_t nl = fread(source, sizeof(char), bufsize, fp);
                if (ferror(fp) != 0) {
                    fputs("Error reading file", stderr);
                } else {
                    source[nl] = '\0';
                    *size = nl;
                }
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return source;
}

void handleErrors(void)
{
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
}

int encrypt(unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *key,
            unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *ciphertext)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

    int len;

    int ciphertext_len;

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        handleErrors();

    /*
     * Initialise the encryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
     * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
     * In this example we are using 256 bit AES (i.e. a 256 bit key). The
     * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
     * is 128 bits
     */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleErrors();

    /*
     * Provide the message to be encrypted, and obtain the encrypted output.
     * EVP_EncryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
     */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
        handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len = len;

    /*
     * Finalise the encryption. Further ciphertext bytes may be written at
     * this stage.
     */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len))
        handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len += len;

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return ciphertext_len;
}

int decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *key,
            unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *plaintext)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

    int len;

    int plaintext_len;

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        handleErrors();

    /*
     * Initialise the decryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
     * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
     * In this example we are using 256 bit AES (i.e. a 256 bit key). The
     * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
     * is 128 bits
     */
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleErrors();

    /*
     * Provide the message to be decrypted, and obtain the plaintext output.
     * EVP_DecryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary.
     */
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
        handleErrors();
    plaintext_len = len;

    /*
     * Finalise the decryption. Further plaintext bytes may be written at
     * this stage.
     */
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len))
        handleErrors();
    plaintext_len += len;

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return plaintext_len;
}

int main (void)
{
    unsigned char *key = (unsigned char *)"59454C4C4F57205355424D4152494E45";
    unsigned char *iv = NULL;

    int decryptedtext_len;
    int ciphertext_len;
    char* ciphertext = readFile("ciphertext.no_newlines_decoded", &ciphertext_len);

    unsigned char decryptedtext[10000];
    decryptedtext_len = decrypt(ciphertext, ciphertext_len, key, iv, decryptedtext);
    decryptedtext[decryptedtext_len] = '\0';
    printf("Decrypted text is:\n");
    printf("%s\n", decryptedtext);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible reason is that you are using *AES-CBC* cipher instead of *AES-ECB* proposed (`EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, **EVP_aes_256_cbc()**, NULL, key, iv)`).

And the actual error is probably caused by passing **NULL** pointer as IV for this CBC cipher (I don't know how this API actually acts in this case, but IV is mandatory for CBC encryption mode).

So try using an appropriate **EVP_aes_128_ecb()** encryption mode.

**UPDATED**

Another thing that will cause `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex` error is that your input data byte length is not a multiple of 16 (*AES* block lenght). Check whether your *ciphertext.no_newlines_decoded* size is a multiple of 16.

The next point is that OpenSSL API operates on bytes rather than zero-terminated strings. So you should pass "rb" instead of "r" to your `fopen` call, and read the bytes without appending any zero terminator.

I also believe that you incorrectly using a key, I think you should define and pass it as given (`unsigned char *key = (unsigned char *)"YELLOW SUBMARINE"`). While using the key in your way won't cause an error you facing, it will result in incorrect decrypted text.

Comment: Ooops. My mistake. Thought I changed this... Thanks for spotting this. But unfortunately, after changing this to 128_ecb nothing changed. Fault is the same :-(

Comment: Oh, I see. Soon I will get to my computer where I can run your code. I will try to find what causes an error and will update my answer

Comment: Henadzi Matuts - you were right. My mistake. Now everything works. Thank you! The password had to be "YELLOW SUBMARINE", without modifying it to ASCII HEX version (as I had to do in command line openssl tool). I mixed this up. Now everything is clear. And the open file mode can be "r", not necessarily "rb". Thanks again.

Comment: @YotKay, finally I was able to run the actual code. Indeed, it works for the right key, so I'm glad my thoughts were helpful. Cocerning "r"/"rb", however, for me it was needed to use "rb", cause fread cuts the input if it meets some special characters (tried it on Windows). There is also one more thing, decrypting with incorrect key causes an error beacuse OpenSSL ciphering context has a padding enabled by default (check EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding function). If you will disable the padding, and try to decrypt the data with some corrupted key, the will be no error rather than invalid plaintext.